# jquery prepend and slide down problem

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to build an application that allows users to upload a song list onto their site. The functions work and when the list is uploaded it slides down and fades in. Here is the Jquery...

```
function list_post() {
    var list_date = $("#list_date").val();
    var team_name = $("#team_name").val();
    var song_list = $("#song_list").val();

    if (list_date == "" || team_name == "" || song_list == ""){
        alert("Please enter a list!");
    }else{
            $.post("scripts/send_list_parse.php", {list_date: list_date, team_name: team_name, song_list: song_list}, function(data){
                $(".list").prepend(data);
                $("#fade").fadeIn(1500);
                $(".list").slideDown(900);
                $("#list_date").val("");
                $("#team_name").val(team_name);
                $("#song_list").val("");
            });
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I upload the second list it doesn't fade in or slide down it just appears. I would like it to fade and slide each time the button is clicked.
Any Ideas?

Here is the send_list_parse.php file...

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("connect_to_mysql.php");
include_once("checkuserlog.php");

if(isset($_POST['list_date']) && ($_POST['song_list']) && ($_POST['team_name'])){
    $list_date = $_POST['list_date'];
             $list_date = stripslashes($list_date);
         $list_date = strip_tags($list_date);
         $list_date = preg_replace('/\r?\n|\r/', "<br />", $list_date);
         $list_date = mysql_real_escape_string($list_date);
         $list_date = str_replace("'", "&#39;", $list_date);
         $list_date = "".$list_date."";
    $song_list = $_POST['song_list'];
         $song_list = stripslashes($song_list);
         $song_list = strip_tags($song_list);
         $song_list = preg_replace('/\r?\n|\r/', "<br />", $song_list);
         $song_list = mysql_real_escape_string($song_list);
         $song_list = str_replace("'", "&#39;", $song_list);
    $team_name = $_POST['team_name'];
         $team_name = stripslashes($team_name);
         $team_name = strip_tags($team_name);
         $team_name = preg_replace('/\r?\n|\r/', "<br />", $team_name);
         $team_name = mysql_real_escape_string($team_name);
         $team_name = str_replace("'", "&#39;", $team_name);

    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO list (date, team_name, song_list) VALUES ('$list_date','$team_name','$song_list')") or die (mysql_error());
    echo '<div id="fade"><span><h4 style="margin-bottom:0px; font-size:14px;">'.$list_date.'</h4>'.$song_list.'<br /></span></div>';
}else{
    echo "Error";
}
?>
```

Here is the portion of the original page where I create the list...

```
$create_song_list = '
        <div class="boxHeader2" style="padding:0px; margin:0 auto;">
        <a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:toggleSlideBox(\'infoBox\');" style="color:white; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none;">&bull;&emsp;Create Song-List</a>
        </div><div class="editBox" id="infoBox" style="color:white; font-size:15px; margin:7px 5px 0px 15px;">
        <input id="list_date" name="list_date" type="text" placeholder="List-Date" style="width:100%;" /><br />
        <textarea id="song_list" name="song_list" placeholder="Song List Here" style="width:100%;" rows="7"></textarea><br />
        <input id="team_name" name="team_name" type="hidden" value="'.$team_name.'" />
        <input id="submit_list" name="submit_list" type="submit" value="submit" onclick="javascript:list_post();" /><br />
        </div>';
```

This is where it is rendered...

```
// ------- Populate Song List ---------------------------
$display_song_list = '';
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM list WHERE team_name='$team_name' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 9"); // Query List
$count_sql = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($count_sql > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $song_list = $row['song_list'];
        $date = $row['date'];
        $display_song_list .= '
    <div class="list" style="display:none;">

        </div>
    <h4 style="margin-bottom:0px; font-size:14px;">'.$date.'</h4>'.$song_list.'<br />';
    }
}
// ------- End Populate Song List -----------------------
```

Comment: try setting the height:0px when the user 'hides' the element

Comment: Where/how are you hiding the elements again, before they reappear? Keep in mind that `list` and `fade` are IDs, and should appear exactly once on the entire page.

Comment: It is a pretty large script but the basic system is this...

Comment: I have a form that posts #list_date and #song_list with the hidden id of #song_team. When it goes to the script; it parses, inserts into a database and creates the #fade div to fade into the screen and it places that div back into the original page into the #list div which slides down. The SELECT out of the database collects the last 10 lists and posts them in the page and the prepend places the new list on top. So the end product is a slide and fade into the screen on top of the preceding lists once it is posted. Now, all of this works perfectly except...

Comment: after I have used the prepend function once it still prepends and saves the information into the database correctly, but it does not slideDown or fade into the screen and I really like the fluidity of those functions as opposed to just a blunt appearance. How can I get the slide and fade to repeat again?

Comment: Secondary Question - Why can you only use an ID only once?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (untested)

```
function list_post() {

    var list_date = $("#list_date").val();
    var team_name = $("#team_name").val();
    var song_list = $("#song_list").val();

    var dataString = 'list_date='+list_date+'&team_name='+team_name+'&song_list='+song_list;

    if (list_date == "" || team_name == "" || song_list == ""){
        alert("Please enter a list!");
    } else {

        $.ajax({
            url: "scripts/send_list_parse.php",
            method: 'POST',
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {$("#fade").fadeIn(1500);},
            success: function(data){
                $("#list").prepend(data).delay(2000).slideDown(900);
                $("#list_date").val("");
                $("#team_name").val(team_name);
                $("#song_list").val("");                
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear how you're marking up the list (I'd hope in either a `<ol>` or `<ul>` but you need to `hide()` the injected elemented before applying `fadeIn()` to it.

Inserting it into the DOM with `prepend()` will just render it there and then.